# Entities not mapped when persistence unit is on EAR level

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, persistence

I need an EAR java application in which I can define a persistence unit and use that persistence unit in different components. For example: I define 2 JAR's in my application.xml: my-product.jar and my-product-module.jar - both of the JAR files should be able to work with the same PersistenceUnit. This PersistenceUnit is defined in a separate jar which is the lib folder of my EAR application.
In the JAR files, there's no other persistence.xml. So in the whole EAR folder: only 1 persistence.xml.

I currently have the following EAR structure. We are deploying on a JBoss 6.1.0.Final server.

```
/
-- lib
|    |
|    -- my-persistence.jar
|           |
|           -- META-INF
|                  |
|                  -- persistence.xml
-- my-product.jar
|
-- my-product.war
|
-- my-product-module.jar
```

My persistence.xml is looking like this:

```
<persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
             version="2.0">
    <persistence-unit name="MyPersistenceUnitName">
                <jta-data-source>java:/MyDatasource</jta-data-source>
                <jar-file>../my-product.jar</jar-file>
                <jar-file>../my-product-module.jar</jar-file>    
                <properties>
                    <property name="jboss.entity.manager.factory.jndi.name" value="java:/MyProduct/ManagerFactory" />
                    <property name="jboss.entity.manager.jndi.name" value="java:/MyProduct/EntityManager" />
            </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

All of this is working fine. The persistence unit gets detected and bounded inside the EAR context.
But, from the moment we create a JPA query and we ask the EntityManager to perform the query, we get the following error:

```
org.hibernate.hql.ast.QuerySyntaxException: MyEntity is not mapped [from MyEntity]
```

So all of our entities are not mapped/detected when the application was loaded. It seems like the jar-file element is not doing what it should do.

How can we detect all of our entities (in both of our JAR's)?
Anybody able to help us out?

Comment: i suggest you to use EJB project that contains all the persistence related data like entities. And add that jar to your required project.

Answer (score 0):

Our solution was to create a custom ANT task which gets all the classes annotated with @Entity (using reflections). This will generate the persistence.xml for us, with  and  nodes. So every class you want to map into the PersistenceContext, needs to be listed in the persistence.xml. This persistence.xml is placed inside a folder META-INF which is wrapped into my-persistence.jar. This jar is placed in the lib folder of my EAR.